# Binding error (binding mismatch?, security mismatch?) when calling a web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soa

Please forgive my lack of experience with WCF, but I'm having an issue with it that I am having some difficulty understanding.

Another organization at the company I work at has created a web service for me to consume.  I believe I have correctly added a Service Reference to my project using the WSDL they provided.  Their web service is based off of an Oracle API that I know very little of, I'm not an Oracle developer.

Here is the code I used to make use of the service reference:

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("https://MYENDPOINT.URL");
MyServiceReference.SERVICENAME_PortTypeClient port = new MyServiceReference.SERVICENAME_PortTypeClient(basicHttpBinding, epa);
port.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = SERVICE_U;
port.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = SERVICE_P;

SOAHeader header = new SOAHeader();
header.Responsibility = SERVICE_RESPONSIBILITY;

InputParameters2 ip2 = new InputParameters2();
ip2.param1 = "abcd";
ip2.param2 = "1234"

OutputParameters2 output = port.WEB_SERVICE_FUNCTION(header, ip2);
```

Here the information in my Web.Config file regarding the binding information:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SERVICENAME_Binding">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://MYENDPOINT.URL"
                 binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SERVICENAME_Binding"
                 contract="MyServiceReference.SERVICENAME_PortType"
                 name=SERVICENAME_Port" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When the call is made to the service I get the following error:

> Security processor was unable to find a security header in the
>   message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or
>   because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.
>   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the
>   client is not using security.

With the following stacktrace:

```
at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at MyProject.MyServiceReference.SERVICE_NAME_PortType.WEB_SERVICE_FUNCTION(WEB_SERVICE_FUNCTIONRequest request)
at MyProject.MyServiceReference.SERVICE_NAME_PortTypeClient.MyProject.MyServiceReference.SERVICE_NAME_PortType.WEB_SERVICE_FUNCTION(WEB_SERVICE_FUNCTIONRequest request) in c:\MyProject\Service References\MyServiceReference\Reference.cs:line 981
at MyProject.MyServiceReference.SERVICE_NAME_PortTypeClient.WEB_SERVICE_FUNCTION(SOAHeader SOAHeader, InputParameters2 InputParameters) in c:\MyProject\Service References\MyServiceReference\Reference.cs:line 988
at MyProject.MyClass.MyFunction(String inputParam) in c:\MyProject\MyClass.asmx.cs:line 160
```

After looking at the stack trace, it appears that the verification of the response may be the issue which lead me to believe that it may have to do with a timestamp issue that others have had (ex. http://blog.latamhub.com/?p=78) may be the issue, but when I try to add the `includeTimestamp="true"` attribute to the `security` tag in the Web.Config file, VS2012 reports that the includeTimestamp attribute is not allowed.  Not quite certain what is going on here or what else to check.  Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT (2013-05-30):

Tried the following custom binding with the `includeTimestamp` set to true and false with no success:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="SERVICENAME_Binding">
        <security 
            includeTimestamp="true"
        />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```